# Unable to enable precision landing via api call

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

I'm working with a Phantom 4 Pro drone, which have precision landing capacity.  I'm using Swift and a iPad for controlling the drone.  In DJI Go software, I can enable it, and it works correctly.  However, in the app that I'm working on, any calls to enable it fails.

This is the code that tries to enable it:

```
static func setPrecisionLandingEnabled(precisionLandingEnabled: Bool, _ completeFunction: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) throws {
    guard let djiKeyManager = DJISDKManager.keyManager() else {
        GLog.Log("Error in Flight Controller Observer. Problem getting djiKeyManager in \(#file) \(#function)")
        throw FlightControllerManager.FlightControllerError.cantGetKeyManager
    }

    guard let precisionLandingEnabledKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightAssistantParamPrecisionLandingEnabled) else {
        GLog.Log("Error in Flight Controller Observer. Problem getting precisionLandingEnabledKey in \(#file) \(#function)")
        throw FlightControllerManager.FlightControllerError.cantGetKey
    }

    djiKeyManager.setValue(precisionLandingEnabled, for: precisionLandingEnabledKey, withCompletion: completeFunction)
}
```

When I call the function, the completion function of DJI SDK returned the following error:

> Error Domain=DJISDKErrorDomain Code=-1013 \"Current product does not
>   support this feature.(code:-1013)\"

The API in question is found here: https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/IntelligentFlightAssistant/DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant.html?search=precision&i=0&#djiintelligentflightassistant_setprecisionlandingenabled_inline

I checked, and there's no parameters passed in when issuing the "take-off" call that is related to precision landing.  So, why am I getting this error when I know that the drone have this feature (as verified by DJI's own app)?  Does the drone have to be flying first before enabling this?  Or are there other conditions that must be met before I can enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you should be creating a `DJIFlightAssistant` object, and then using the existing method `setPrecisionLandingEnabled(_: Bool, completion: DJICompletionBlock)`

Why are you writing your own `setPrecisionLandingEnabled()` method?

Comment: Ah, I was confused because there was a dictionary key that could be used to modify different properties such as max flight height, and I confused this with that.  Using the method you suggested worked, thanks!